# ¿como se les llama a los filtros de imágenes en css?

Tags: filtros-css

Hay unos filtros, que son imágenes de puntitos, líneas, zig zags, etc, que son unas simples rayitas con fondo transparente, que uno pone sobre una foto, creando un efecto interesante.

Esas imágenes pequeñitas tienen un nombre. Y como no recuerdo el nombre, no puedo buscar varios modelos para descargarlas.

**¿Alguien sabe el nombre de estos filtros?**

Alguna vez seguro han visto una imagen "dividida" en cuadraditos pequeños.. A eso me refiero.

Comment: Hola ray, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera medalla! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, es muy importante leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), saludos :)

Comment: Me gustaría ver un ejemplo de los filtros de "puntitos, líneas, zig zags".

Comment: Así como @Shaz, yo también quisiera ver los ejemplos de lo que dices. Por favor, edita tu pregunta agregando imágenes o enlaces a sitios donde se ve el efecto que deseas.

Comment: Aqui un ejemplo: http://fusion.pe

Comment: creo que te refieres a png patterns o transparent textures

Comment: +Leonardo Cabré. Ese es el nombre, gracias.

Comment: Ya pueden cerrar el tema si quieren, y eliminar el link de la págin que puse de ejemplo, o como quieran.... Gracias a todos.

Comment: Si hay una forma de dar puntos a quien me ayudó o algo, avísenme por fa, que no sé nada porque soy nuevo.

Comment: @LeonardoCabré parece que tu comentario resolvió el tema. Puedes publicarlo como respuesta :)

Comment: @ray Puedes aceptar la respuesta en el tick que hay a la izquierda de la pregunta que te ayudó. De esta manera, marcas la respuesta como aceptada y los usuarios posteriores podrán ver cual ha sido la solución que te ha servido.

Answer (score 3):

Son llamados PNG Patterns o Transparent Textures.

**EDIT (Añadido de ejemplo)**

Para aplicar un pattern a un background podemos hacerlo a través del selector `:after`.

Para poder ver la imagen con y sin pattern añadí un pequeño jquery para que "active" o "desactive" el pattern haciendo click sobre la misma.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".pattern").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("nopattern");
  })
})
```

```css
.pattern{
  background: url(https://www.anipedia.net/imagenes/que-comen-los-perros.jpg) no-repeat ;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.pattern:after{
  background: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/brushed-alum.png") repeat;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.pattern.nopattern:after{
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pattern"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo? Me parece interesante el tema.

Comment: Añadido @LuisFernando